# Make the recent screen show today's detail by default

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

On the recent screen it makes no sense that you click the icon and get presented a blank page.

The today tab being the first valid option should be defaulted.

Comment: A better suggestion is the following: if the envelope is white, show today's screen when clicked. If it's yellow, show the recent screen.

Comment: @Koper - Oo... I like that.

Comment: @koper - that would be a nicer solution indeed.

Comment: I would like that the feature would be implemented as suggested by Kop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a blank page if something has happened recently that you haven't seen yet. The default view is to show "recent" activity, hence the name.

There won't be any new activity to show in the "recent" view if the orange envelope isn't orange.

[image: activity]

[image: no activity]

Answer (score 1):

You might be better served by an external tracking service, such as Jon Skeet's RepTrac:

http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=2915&sf=706&su=1254&meta=2915&mode=today&showzero=true&showflair=true

Replace my user numbers with your user numbers.  It always defaults to today.

The "recent" page is for "recent" activity, as indicated by the new activity envelope icon at the top of the page to the left of your username.  The "today" and other buttons are available for you to select a different time period than 'recent' but the 'recent' page is intentionally designed to support the envelope "recent activity" indicator.

Perhaps what you really want is a separate link or button that goes to the recent page and selects the "today" time period for you.  If so, please modify your request, otherwise this is likely to be closed as by design.

Comment: Wow, I fail at using the same quoting style throughout a single post.